# Is there any way to launch app downloaded from app store in iPhone using shell script in real devices

Tags: ios, shell, bundle-identifier

Is there any way to launch app downloaded from app store in iPhone using shell script in real devices

Tried running idevicedebug -u "$DEVICE_UDID" run "$APP_BUNDLE_ID"
but getting error
Please make sure to mount the developer disk image first:

1. Get the iOS version from `ideviceinfo -k ProductVersion`.
2. Find the matching iPhoneOS DeveloperDiskImage.dmg files.
3. Run `ideviceimagemounter` with the above path.
   The os version of phone is 14.4.2 and xcode is 14

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using following steps:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ideviceinstaller
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies usbmuxd
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libplist
sudo rm /var/db/lockdown/*     
brew install --HEAD libplist
brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
brew unlink usbmuxd
brew link usbmuxd
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller
```